# Primary occupation for the US visa - student or professional?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, study, applications

I'm going to the US this May for an official event for students (ACM ICPC World Finals). I have a host invitation, I even have my name written in some special lists for the consulate.

Also, though being a student, I'm now part-time employed. I don't know what to write in a visa form as my primary occupation: student or worker? If I select that I'm a student then I cannot enter my job information (only option is *previous* job, and the date of dismission must be not later than today); same for vice-versa.

What is important that I'm working as a software engineer, and specialists in this area sometimes attract additional attention. Thus not filling job information may look really suspicious.

As of now I mentioned that my main occupation is a student and filled my current job as a previous job (with current date as a dismissal date), leaving a comment that in fact I'm still employed.

What should I answer to this question? It seems that I have to write incorrect or incomplete information in either way.

Comment: Are you a full-time student? Then I guess that is your primary occupation.

Comment: @JoErNanO Yes, I am. But where should I notify the consulate about my job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are filing DS-160

Your primary occupation is being a full-time student. If there is a field for explanation, please provide an additional explanation over there.

Alternatively, you can select "Other" and provide full explanation.